# Google Cloud Run is not able to connect to MongoDB instance in Compute Engine

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-run

This is the infrastructure:

- Cloud Run: Container with a NodeJS API.
- Compute Engine: MongoDB instance.
- Network: Both in the same region.
- Network: VPC Connector created on default network provided by Google.

What I have seen:

- Compute Engine's MongoDB is authenticating the user from Google cloud but it start killing the connections
- I have a public API and I am able to connect from my local machine. Database, users and so are properly created.
- I got error 503. See compete error at the very bottom

**Mongo Configuration**

- Compute Engine on Ubuntu 18...
- No any special configuration rather than updating the mongo.conf.
- URI `mongodb://<user>:<pass>@12.34.56.78:27017/?authSource=cubicup-int&maxPoolSize=300&waitQueueTimeoutMS=750000&maxConnecting=300`

**Driver**

```
"doc":{"driver":{"name":"nodejs","version":"3.6.11"}
```

**Mongo.conf**

[image]

**530 error**
[image]
[image]

Comment: Edit your question with details. What is reporting the 503 error? How is MongoDB configured? Which version? Which driver and driver version? Cloud Run configuration? You mention that MongoDB starts killing the connections. Unless you have confined Cloud Run Always On, the container will go to sleep and connections will fail. If you are using a global connection handle to MongoDB in Cloud Run, then you need to detect connection problems and handle automatically reconnecting, otherwise, connect 
when required, and before returning close the handle. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Right now everything is happening on the Internet (Public) I removed the VPC connectors and open a public IP. In fact I can connect from my local. The server is not running, is not starting because I cannot connect to MongoDB

Comment: Your update did not answer most of my questions. The 503 error is for `favicon.ico`. Your code is crashing on that HTTP request.